# android replace confirm on contextual action bar

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I want to delete the confirm button that appears on left side of CAB when my app si in selection mode. Or replace it with a back button.

I have a single selection mode, so, in contextual action bar I need only title, and a back button.

I follow android tutorial and all work fine, but now how can I remove default confirm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the icon on the top left by changing it in the theme.

If you styles.xml, create a new theme if you don't have one already.

```
<style name="Theme.Custom.Light" parent="Holo.Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_checkmark</item>
</style>
```

You can put in any drawable here. Just tried it and it worked.

Comment: ok, it's work. I want only know how could I intercept click event on this button. Default behavior is to close current contextual action mode by calling onDestroyActionMode in ActionMode.Callback .

Comment: You can't detect it directly. You will have to do what you want in onDestroyActionMode.